# WPF data binding setter loop?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, infinite-loop

### Background

I have a ListBox containing `ParentViewModel` items:

```
<listBox x:Name="lstParentItems"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ParentItems}"
         SelectedItem={Binding SelectedParent, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
</ListBox>
```

Each parent instance has a list of child items: `ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> ChildItems`. When I select a parent item, I display the list of children in another listbox:

```
<!-- displays a list of ChildViewModels for currently selected ParentViewModel -->
<ListBox x:Name="lstChildItems" DataContext={Binding SelectedParent}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChild, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
         SelectionChanged="lstChildItems_SelectionChanged"
         MouseDoubleClick="lstChildItems_MouseDoubleClick">
</ListBox>
```

As you can see, I want the Parent instance to know which Child is currently selected.

### The problem

While debugging a different bug, I discovered a weird behavior, some kind of *setter loop*. I put a debugging breakpoint to the SelectedChild setter, which looks like this:

```
public ChildViewModel SelectedChild {
    get { return _selectedChild; }
    set {
        _selectedChild = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedChild");
    }
}
```

**When I select a child item, the setter doesn't called once, but executes over and over.** The debugger keeps pausing at the breakpoint (the RaisePropertyChanged line) and after clicking Continue, immediately pauses at the same place again.

I have no idea where could this behavior be coming from. Any ideas where to start looking?
I'll be happy to provide any required details. So far, I should mention that:

- the `SelectedChild` property doesn't take part in any other binding (XAML or code)
- `SelectedChild` is *never* assigned to in code
- in the `ChildViewModel` I have a CanCommandExecute method that checks if `SelectedChild != null`
- the code-behind event handlers in `lstChildItems` are used to interact with a COM control that was hard to directly incorporate into my MVVM architecture; all they do is read some information about the `SelectedChild` if it isn't null; no assigning

Comment: how are you filling ChildItems on parent change?

Comment: Each of the parents that is displayed in the `lstParents` ListBox already has a list of children in memory. There's no "filling" taking place on selected parent change.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `RaisePropertyChanged` from your setter unless the value _actually_ changed, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your bullet points holds your answer:

• in the ChildViewModel I have a CanCommandExecute method that checks if SelectedChild != null

It is nothing more than the `CanCommandExecute` method calling your `SelectedChild` property repeatedly. It will call it every time the UI gets or loses focus, which includes every time you press F5 to continue.

When my applications are running, I actually use this method to get execution into my view models whenever I need to... just put a break point into the `CanExecute` part of my `ICommand` and go back to the UI and the break point is instantly hit... very useful... once you know what's happening.

Comment: That sounded like a good explanation, but unfortunately, this is not the case :( I commented out the null check in CanCommandExecute, and changed it just to `return true;`, but the behavior is still the same. Also, why would it be calling the setter, not just the getter?

Comment: That's a good point... then search your `Entire Solution` for `'SelectedChild = '`... one of your Find Results *must* be being called. Comment out each one until you find the offending line and then you can work out why it's getting called. I still think it sounds like something to do with a `CanCommandExecute` method.

Comment: Searched the entire solution. Nothing. I only **read** the value a couple of times, but never assign to it, aside from the one XAML binding.

Comment: @oli.G... so what was the solution?

Comment: You were right, it was about UI getting and losing focus. I also figured out why the SETTER gets called - when the UI loses focus, even if I have an item selected, the framework apparently sets it to null. When the UI receives focus again, selected item is set to its original value. I found out by using a MessageBox instead of a breakpoint. The good old god damn MessageBox sometimes really beats any debuggers and logging :)

Comment: What is weird is that the other listbox, containing ParentViewModels, doesn't do this - the messagebox never shows up on minimize/maximize, only when I actually click a different item. Some serious under the hood stuff here, I guess :)

Comment: Thanks for updating so future users can benefit from the solution.